# s-wave, p-wave or d-wave collisions in scattering theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, scattering

In scattering theory, what is a good intuitive picture to think of s-wave, p-wave or d-wave collisions ? What is their importance and what are the examples where a particular one is assumed to be the only important one and rest are taken as negligible ?

Comment: This seems a very broad question. You're essentially asking for a review article on scattering. There must be something along these lines out there in Googlespace.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is to remember these quantum numbers correspond to angular momentum. S wave is the zero angular momentum  quantum number , l=0, and will correspond to a classical head on collision. P is l=1 and d l=2 which means higher angular momentum between scatterer and incoming. The atomic orbitals would give some intuition about functional shapes of the Y_l_m functions http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbitals

Answer (score 7):

I found the very last paragraph of the following answer quite explanatory:
https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/8324/46100

> **Interpretation of the Partial Wave Expansion:** In the literature, you will often come across terms such as $s$-wave scattering. The
>   partial wave expansion decomposes the scattering process into the
>   scattering of incoming waves with definite angular momentum quantum
>   number. It explains in which way $s$-, $p$-, $d$-waves etc. are
>   affected by the potential. For low energy scattering, only the first
>   few $l$-quantum numbers are affected. If all but the first term are
>   discarded, only the $s$-waves take part in the scattering process.
>   This is an approximation that is, for example, made in the scattering
>   of the atoms in a Bose-Einstein condensate.