# Phase shift calculation in quantum scattering for potential $V=a/r^2 $. Neumann function missing

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, potential, scattering

I'm tasked of finding the phase shifts for scattering from a potential of the form $V=a/r^2$.

My thinking is as follows. For this specific potential I can bring the differential equation to the form:
$$[{{d^2} \over {d^2r}} + {{2} \over {r}}  {{d} \over {dr}} +k^2{_E} - {{l^{eff}(l^{eff} +1)} \over {r^2}}] R^l (r)=0 ,$$ for which we know the solutions(Bessel and Neumann). Note that: $$l^{eff} = -1/2 +\sqrt{1/4+l(l+1)+2ma}=-1/2+ \sqrt{(l+1/2)^2 +2ma}. $$

We now take the solution to infinity for two occasions:

1) $a=0$, that means out of the range of the potential.

I would say that the solution is a superposition of Bessel and Neumann function for the long distance approximation. Something like:

$$R^l_{V=0}(r)= Asin(k_E - lπ/2) + Bcos(k_E=lπ/2) .$$  I think we have to consider a Neumann function because here we exclude zero .

2) Similarly the solution for a non zero (we may include zero for $r$):
$$R' = {{k} \over {\sqrt{u}}} {{sin(k_E- l^{eff}π/2)} \over {k_{E}r}} ={{k} \over {\sqrt{u}}} {{sin(k_E- lπ/2 +δ_l)} \over {k_{E}r}}  .$$

We must equate the two equations to find our result for the phase shifts.

My question arrives from the fact that all solution I have found based on a similar logic do not include the Neumann function in both cases, that is they consider the value $r=0$ for $r\to \infty$ even where the potential is zero.

So **my question** (I have also read this: [Phase shifts in scattering theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8132/)) is why do we exclude zero in both cases. Why not take Neumann function in the area where the effect of the potential is zero?

Thank you.

Comment: @QMechanic  Thank you for the edit. I just wrote again the thank you at the end. Appreciate it.