# Example of calculating phase shifts in scattering theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, nuclear-physics, scattering, scattering-cross-section

I have an extended question to this post:

[Phase shifts in scattering theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8132/)

I have read it and also went over the formalism in Sakurai's, Shankar's, and Griffith's. I am now trying to look for examples of applications. All of the examples that I have found in the texts evolve either hard-sphere potential or square well potential, which are nice but they are very specific. I am trying to look for a more general example that has the form of $\frac{a}{r}$ or $\frac{a}{r^2}$ or $\frac{a}{r^3}$ ..., where $a$ can be positive or negative.

- So, for example, if given a potential of $\frac{a}{r^2}$, how does one find the exact phase shifts?